# I can't print hello world in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image]I created a folder named " Python Trial ", and a folder within it named test and within that folder i created a file named test.py

I installed the python extension and tried to print " Hello World! " however it keeps on giving me this command:
C:/Users/saram/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/saram/Documents/Python Trial/test/test.py"
-bash: C:/Users/saram/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe: No such file or directory

I don't know what to do

I tried reinstalling visual studio code and the python extension but it kept on giving me the same error message

Comment: did you install python in your system? If not then go [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) download and install it properly.

Comment: Check if the `C:/Users/saram/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe` path in the error message is correct, is there a python interpreter there? Follow this [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to start using python in vscode.

Comment: Hey everyone thank you for your time to answer but I am still struggling to run my code. I downloaded the interpreter and it is still giving me the same error message

Comment: I removed and reinstalled everything and I still can print hello world in vscode, I added an image to help with my issue.

Comment: What terminal are you using? Is it possible to switch terminals and use [powershell or cmd](https://imgur.com/sLPEbOB) successfully?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu terminal, I switched to cmd and powershell in VScode, but I don't know where to go from there to run print hello world

Comment: Follow the answer and docs step by step. If you get an error, describe to Northwest every step you took and show your ethics interface and detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Download [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extensions
3. create folder
4. open folder in vscode
5. New *name.py* script
6. run code

You can also install [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension to run code.

Follow the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) step by step and you will get the output.